# YAML is annoying on DNS addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]

Tags: dns, netplan

```
~# sudo netplan apply
/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml:16:18: Error in network definition: address '8.8.8.8' is missing /prefixlength
      addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
                 ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
network:
 version: 2
 ethernets: {}
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
  ens160:
  dhcp4: no
  addresses: [206.80.236.251/29]
  gateway4: 206.80.236.249
  nameservers: 
    addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Make sure you are spacing correctly at exactly this stage :

```
nameserver
```

should be aligned with `gateway` & `addresses` while spacing